# How can I create a patch of ocean that blends seamlessly into the horizon?

Tags: godot

The tagline pretty much says it, but here's a picture to show the problem:[image: Shoreline]

The darker gradient of blue on the horizon comes from the Godot WorldEnvironment, while the lighter shade results from a half-transparent plane that will later be animated with waves.
How can I make the ocean plane blend into the horizon?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a possible answer. The Spatial Material property "Distance Fade" appears to produce the kind of effect I had in mind: [image: Distance Fade settings]

After doubling the size of my ocean plane from 1000 to 2000, here's what the result looks like:
[image: With Distance Fade]